# How to get last word from string In jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Getting  a String Like:

```
Mon Jul 10 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0000
```

I want To use Only  `03:00` from the string in jQuery. How Can I split the string to get this through jQuery Or JavaScript?

I want only time from The result.

Comment: dont split reformat it using date and get the data you need

Comment: How are you getting the string ? Are you getting the string from date object ?

Comment: I'm curios what do you use to return that result...Please share your code.

Comment: Show us how you are getting this string.

Comment: var date=events.start;
                     console.log(date.split(' ')); Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the incorrect approach. You don't want to start hacking this string around. Instead, convert it to a Date object then get the hours and minutes from it:

```js
var date = new Date('Mon Jul 10 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0000');
var time = ('00' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);
console.log(time);
```

Comment: I wrote the same answer. I guess there's a problem... Why does it show `04:00` for both of us?

Comment: GMT is currently -1 to UTC

Comment: Ha ha... Now I get it.

Comment: I updated the answer to use the `getUTC*()` methods to avoid the discrepancy between the string and output, as that's most likely what the OP needs.

Comment: Can you give some more constructive feedback. As you can see from the snippet this works fine, given the information in your question.

Comment: GMT = UTC (as close as...), if you're in the UK then your current time is BST which is +1 hour.

Comment: Great ANswer thanx.

Comment: One more problem is there it giving me the result in 24 hrs i want it on 12 hrs.. like 4:00 pm its giving 16:00 i dnt want it

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a normal string, but a time string. You might need to parse it and then get the hours and minutes:

```js
var str = "Mon Jul 10 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0000";
var time = new Date(str);
console.log(("0" + time.getHours()).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + time.getMinutes()).substr(-2));
```